# Overriding profile dependencies from parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am using maven 3.1 and my project inherits from a third party parent pom. The parent pom has a profile which must not be activated as it introduces conflicting dependencies.

In order to prevent the parent's profile from kicking in, I tried defining an "empty" profile with the same id in the child pom - hoping it will override the one from the parent, but that did not work for me.

Is it possible and if so how can you override dependencies introduced by a profile in the parent pom ?

Comment: why do you inherit from the 3rd party parent pom? For the  `dependencies`, `dependencyManagement` or `pluginManagement` sections? Only some of them, all of them or something else completely?

Comment: That's a shame. You could `import` the parent into your pom's `dependencyManagement` section and declare a `<type>pom</type>` dependency to the parent pom in your `dependency` section as alternative ways of achieving the first two, but I don't know of a work around for the `pluginManagement` section.

Answer (score 3):

You may explicitly deactivate the profile on the command line by putting a '!' in front of the profile ID, e.g.

```
mvn -P !profileIdFromParent install
```

More on profile activation in the [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I want. Would be pretty could if this could be done setting a property in the child pom so I don't have to remember using that -P command line parameter. Besides, my project is part of a multiple module pom. Unfortunately, another module needs the profile I am trying to weed out for my child project.